# Spark dataframe select a column from a row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I want to create a df with one column from a df with multiple columns. See this pseudo code:

```
df=[(id1,text),(id2,text2),...] //df where each row has two columns "id","text"
id_column=df.map(row=>row._1)
```

How can I do this in spark??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it!!
What I wanted was:

```
having a df like:
| id | text  |
| 1  |  bla1 |     
| 2  | foo   |
//real scala/spark code...
just_ids=df.map(row=>row.getAs[Int](0))
```

Comment: Creating a df does not involve .show. E.g. second line does not result in df.

Comment: Actually your intent is unclear as you do it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a select

```
val df : DataFrame=[(id1,text),(id2,text2),...] //df where each row has two columns "id","text"

val dfResult: DataFrame = df.select("id")
```

If you don't know the name of the column and know the position, you can also do:

```
df.select(aux.columns(0))
```